# Capybara vs Page Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, page-object-gem

I'm currently using Cucumber and [Ruby Page Object](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object) for testing my Ruby on Rails website.

I'm trying to understand [Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) and decide if I should add it to the mix, or maybe replace Page Object with it.

I'd appreciate if somebody provides more insights into benefits of using Capybara when compared to Page Object, and does it make sense to use them together?

Thanks

Comment: Capybara supports many more drivers such as Poltergeist. Both are pretty active but Capybara has about 4x as many contributors.

Comment: Thanks to Justin Ko's answer I now understand that question Capybara vs Page Object is not valid because they are different things. Better question would be Capybara vs Selenium or Watir, but for that I already found plenty of opinions. I just wander if I should delete this question or leave it here for the people that may have wrong understanding as I had?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use Cheezy's page-object gem with Capybara.

The page-object gem only supports Watir-Webdriver and Selenium-WebDriver. It does not support Capybara.

Capybara, Watir and Selenium are for driving browsers while page-object is for modelling your pages. If you switch to Capybara, you would need to pick a different page-object library such as [SitePrism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism). Switching would mean you either need to support two completely separate stacks or re-write your existing tests.